# How can I configure nginx to use 2 docroots (with different hostnames) with ddev

Tags: nginx-config, ddev

I want to use 2 web sites inside a ddev web container but can't find out how to configure nginx the right way.
I have set up the additional_hostname to site-a and site-b to let me access the web site with site-a.ddev.site and site-b.ddev.site. The web sites are in different local directories site-a and site-b.

How can I define the "sites-available" and "sites-enabled" configuration for nginx?
In the documentation I found only the way to create a .ddev/nginx-site.conf file, but with this I can only configure one web site.

I know that I can "ddev ssh" into the container and configure it by hand, but it should configure automatic when I checkout the project and made a "ddev configure" and "ddev start".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different hostnames is really easy, you just use `additional_hostnames` or `additional_fqdns` in .ddev/config.yaml. See [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/additional-hostnames/).

But from the context of your question, I assume you want to have two different docroots in the nginx config, which respond to different hostnames. If that's right, here are some options:

1. Just use two different ddev projects. This is the easiest technique if the code for the two projects isn't already a mono-repo and tightly coupled.
2. Add a .ddev/nginx-site.conf to override the nginx configuration. (This is the "legacy" technique in [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-nginx-configuration)). There is an example of the exact technique you want in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1889#issuecomment-543306759 - There @jcrichto adds an additional http server to the default configuration like this (but read the entire issue):

```
#######################################################
# EXAMPLE SITE ADDED TO DEFAULT NGINX
# THIS ASSUMES server_name: matches a name added to 
# additional_hostnames: in your config.yaml
# 
# CANADA - EN
#######################################################
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ca.example.com.ddev.site;

    #redifne your root
    root /var/www/html/lang/en_ca;

    include /etc/nginx/nginx_default.conf;

    # this directive is unique to our set up, but demonstrates
    # you can do more directives per site like this
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/html/lang/en_ca;
    }
}
```

The same issue is tackled the same way in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1850#issuecomment-547461968 for more context.

Comment: With this configuration as a template. I have it got working.